# Twit Pic Engine problem in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'm using TwitPic Engine for posting twitter through my iPhone Application. it posting successfully but i have one problem is that can't post the image continuously. It takes 3 min different between two images. otherwise error message is come.

Please give me the solution or any other API for posting the image in twitter....

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Daniel-"twit pic failed to upload" this is the error message

Comment: any one please clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for posting the image to twitter and this is the open source project, so it might be helpful for you. Refer this [Link](http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/).
Type this into your terminal:

```
   svn checkout http://tweetero.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tweetero-read-only
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cant send the same image continuously  as per twitter.. after posting any tweet or any thing we can send send the same image we we send previously